# How to detect Auto Sync state changed via broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

Currently I am working on the widget that has several **toggle features, and one of them is Auto-Sync toggle.** 
I managed to implement enabling and disabling of the Auto-Sync using flowing code.

```
public class AutoSyncUtility {

    private static final String TAG = "Toggler_AutoSyncUtility";

    public static void setEnabled(Context context, boolean isEnabled) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Called setEnabled");

        try {
            ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(isEnabled);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(exception));
        }
    }

    public static boolean isEnabled(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Called isEnabled");
        boolean isEnabled = false;
        try {
                isEnabled = ContentResolver.getMasterSyncAutomatically();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(exception));
        }

        return isEnabled;
    }

}
```

Beside that, I need to register broadcast receiver that will detect Auto-Sync state changed from other apps (either from settings or via other widget).
**Is there some action that can be added to intent filter in manifest?**

Other solution that is possible solution is to `implement SyncStatusObserver interface` and use

```
public void onStatusChanged(int which);

Object handleObject = ContentResolver.addStatusChangeListener(ContentResolver.SYNC_OBSERVER_TYPE_SETTINGS, 
    new SyncStatusObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(int which) {}
    );
}
```

**But problem with this solution is that every time I launch some other app or turn off/on screen that listener unregistered it self, and handle object becomes null.**

Is there any workarounds?

**====== Latest update *(workaround)* ====== **

```
public class AutoRotateContentObserver extends ContentObserver {


    public static interface AutoRotateStateChangedListener {
        void autoRotateStateChanged();
    }

    private AutoRotateStateChangedListener mListener;

    public AutoRotateContentObserver(Handler handler,
            AutoRotateStateChangedListener listener) {
        super(handler);
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        mListener.autoRotateStateChanged();
        super.onChange(selfChange);

    }
}


public class MyService extends Service implements
        AutoRotateStateChangedListener {
    private AutoRotateContentObserver mAutoRotateContentObserver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mAutoRotateContentObserver = new AutoRotateContentObserver(new Handler(), this);

        getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
                Settings.System.getUriFor(Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION),
                false, mAutoRotateContentObserver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(mAutoRotateContentObserver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void autoRotateStateChanged() {         
        // doSomething();
    }
}


public class AutoRotateUtility {

    public static boolean isEnabled(Context context) {        
        try {
            return (Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION) != 0) ? true : false;            
        } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        }        
        return false;
    }

    public static void setEnabled(Context context, boolean isEnabled) {
        try {
            Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, isEnabled ? 1 : 0);                        
        } catch (Exception e) {    
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: do you got solution?????????????please help if you got it i am facing same problem

Comment: I've updated my question by adding working solution. Hope it suits your needs...

Comment: Thanks ,l'll try this soon and inform you working or not...

Comment: How to listen in a BroadcastReceiver (onReceive) ether Auto-sync data is turning on/off ?